# iScroll refresh not working

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, iscroll4, iscrollview

I implemented iScroll-Scroller programmatically with these lines:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit',function( event, data ){

$("[id='menu']").attr("data-iscroll","");
$("[data-iscroll]").iscrollview();

});
```

Whenever i change the height of the site, e.g. by rotating the device the iscroll-wrapper doesn't adapt it's size. Meaning that i cannot scroll to the buttom anymore. So i (tried) to build a function to refresh the wrapper's size:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {

$("[data-iscroll]").jqmData('iscrollview').refresh();

 setTimeout(function () {
$("[data-iscroll]").jqmData('iscrollview').refresh();

    }, 0)


}, false);
```

This doesn't work at at all and i have no idea why. Let me know if you need more code (tried to keep it as short as possible).

Comment: First tell me, do you have more then one iscrollview implemented. I think I know what is your problem.

Comment: Yes. It's a facebook-like webapp, wheras the menu is usually hidden behind the actual content. Both content and menu are scrolled with iscrollview

Answer (score 1):

My solution is:

```
        setTimeout(function () {
            iScroll.refresh();
            window.scrollTo(0);
        }, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you wanna use `iScroll` when jQuery Mobile supports [listview](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/lists/index.html) and [fixed header](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html) and footer??

`iScroll` is buggy with jQuery-mobile in my experience. I wouldn't recommend it for any developers.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$("[data-iscroll]").iscrollview().iscrollview('refresh');
```

then

```
$('[data-iscroll]').trigger('create');
```